# Notion.so question - Automatically create rows in a notion database when a row in another database is created

Tags: notion-api

Is there a way to automatically create rows in a child database when a row is created in a parent database?

The use case is customer onboard. We want to create a customer row and then have the onboarding steps created as rows in a child, 'onboarding', database so that each step can be treated as its own row with its own properties like completed date, notes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it immediately, because there is no official notion webhooks

But you can check new database items every 1 minute https://www.make.com/en/help/apps/productivity/notion#watch-database-items

And then you can create new item https://www.make.com/en/help/apps/productivity/notion#create-a-database-item